# Android - Calculate the average info received by webservice

Tags: android, json

I have to calculate the average weather info (temperature, humidity, dewpoint and pressure) from http://ghelfer.net/weather.aspx?output=json . 
Receive it using JSONArray, calculate and show each average on the screen. I don't know how to populate the arrays with the separated info (a array to temperature, other to humidity, other to dewpoint and another one for pressure).
How do I do it?

Edit------ (This is what I tried)

```
JSONObject res = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray array1 = res.getJSONArray("temperature");
for (int i = 0; i<array1.length();i++){
    float add = 0;
    add += Integer.parseInt(array1[i], array1.length());
}
```

Edit2 --------

```
public void onClickWheater(View view){
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute(opa);
    }

    class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           if(params.equals(opa)){
               try {
               HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://ghelfer.net/weather.aspx?output=json");
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
               int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                   String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                   return data;

           } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           } else {

               try {
                   HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + params[0] + "/json/");
                   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);

                   int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                   if (status == 200) {
                       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                       String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                       return data;
                   }


               } catch (Exception e) {
                   return null;
               }

           }
            return null;
        }
```

The code in Else works perfectly.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show what code you've tried?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry! Edited :)

Comment: You need to `getJSONArray("weather")`... temperature is not the name of the array

Comment: Whatever `opa` is, I'm guessing that `if(params.equals(opa))` is not true because `params` is a `String[]` and calling `.equals` on an array is usually never a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to calculate averages, you don't need to save separate lists, you can just accumulate the data that you need. But, first, you have to parse it correctly.

- `res.getJSONArray("temperature");` is not correct. If you look at the JSON data, then `"weather"` is the name of the array.
- `array1[i]` won't compile because `JSONArray` is not indexable
- `float add = 0` would reset your counter for every object in the array
- `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` is not applicable to the parameters you gave

Here is what you should do instead.

```
double avgTemp = 0.0;
double avgHumid = 0.0;

double tempSum = 0.0;
double humidSum = 0.0;

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray weather = json.getJSONArray("weather");
int dataLength = weather.length();

for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
    JSONObject tempObj = weather.getJSONObject(i);

    tempSum += tempObj.getDouble("temperature");
    humidSum += tempObj.getDouble("humidity");

}

if (dataLength != 0) {
    avgTemp = tempSum/dataLength;
    avgHumid = humidSum/dataLength;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, apparently it worked. But for some reason, I don't receive any info from the webservice. My "result" is coming null.

Comment: You'd have to show more code for how you read from the webpage. I used Volley and this code worked.

Comment: I would post a new question, instead. I already answered your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Parse json into model class using Gson Once model is created create seperate ArrayList as follows

```
        WheatherModel model = new WheatherModel();
        model=(WheatherModel)response; //after parsing json to model class

        for i=0; i<model.size();i++)
        {
            ArrayList<String> humidity = new ArrayList<>();
            humidity.add(model.getHumidity());

        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume Gson is being used.